# Prove that $ \pi_g $ is a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Suppose that $ G $ is group and $ g $ is any element from $ G $ ($g \in G $). We define a function $ \pi_g : G \rightarrow G,\ \ \pi_g(x) = g \cdot x$. Prove that $ \pi_g $ is a permutation of the set $ G $.

Could you show me how to prove this theorem?
Thank for your help.

Comment: Try to find an inverse. In this case that is the most direct way to show injectivity and surjectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to prove that $\pi_g$ is a bijection, that is, a one-to-one onto mapping.

To do this requires proving two things: (i) if $\pi_g(s)=\pi_g(t)$ then $s=t$ and (ii) for any $y\in G$, there is an $x\in G$ such that $\pi_g(x)=y$.

Item (i): Suppose $gs=gt$. Multiplying on the left by the inverse of $g$, we get $s=t$. Item (ii): Your turn!

Comment: Can you look on my proof injective in @Berci's answer?

Comment: You perhaps should have explained *why* you conclude that $x=y$. Also, you have $g$ on the wrong side. Should say $gx=gy$, therefore $g^{-1}(gx)=g^{-1}(gy)$. But $g^{-1}(gx)=(g^{-1}g)x=ex=x$. Similarly, $g^{-1}(gy)=y$.

Comment: I want show, that $ \pi_g(x) = g \cdot x $ is bijective. So: $ \pi(g) = g \cdot x \Rightarrow y = g \cdot x \Rightarrow x = \frac{y}{g} $ And we substitute $ \pi_g(x) = \pi_g(\frac{y}{g}) = g \cdot \frac{y}{g} = y $ So it's also surjective, proof is good?

Comment: Basic idea is fine. Usually we write $g^{-1}y$, not $\frac{y}{g}$. So you should also. Given $y$, we want to produce an $x$ such that $\pi_g(x)=y$. It is easy to verify that $x=g^{-1}y$ works, for $g(g^{-1}y)=(gg^{-1})y=ey=y$.

Comment: Yes it's my falut, I forgot, that we can write in this method. So it's all task?

Comment: I think we have covered everything!

Comment: thank you so much, it was very important for me :)

Comment: You are welcome. It takes a little while until you get used to the notation.

Answer (score 3):

Can you show that $\pi_{g^{-1}}$ is an inverse of $\pi_g$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** you have to prove that the function $\pi_g$ is *injective* ($gx=gy\implies x=y$) and *surjective* (all elements arise in the form $gx$).

Comment: $ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \pi_g(x) = \pi_g(y) \Rightarrow x = y $ I must prove it, so I don't understand only this "$ g $" in $\pi_g(x) $, but: Suppose $$ \pi_g(x) = \pi_g(y) \Rightarrow x \cdot g = y \cdot g \Rightarrow x = y $$ Therefore is injective. It's can be?

Comment: That looks fine, but you might want to explain what property of groups you are using to get the last implication.